# Fatal Error - Too many open files

Tags: php, phpunit

I try to run PHPUnit Tests in my new machine and I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/usr/lib/php/pear/File/Iterator): failed to open dir: Too many open files' in /usr/lib/php/pear/File/Iterator/Factory.php:114

The same code on the old machine run well...

New machine environment:
PHP Version: PHP 5.3.21 (cli)
Older: PHP 5.3.14

PHPUnit output every time:

```
................EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE 65 / 66 ( 98%)
E

Time: 34 seconds, Memory: 438.50Mb

There were 50 errors:

1) XXXXXXXXXXX
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/usr/lib/php/pear/File/Iterator): failed to open dir: Too many open files' in /usr/lib/php/pear/File/Iterator/Factory.php:114
```

Comment: Are you forgetting to call `fclose`?

Comment: fclose? sorry but I don't understand your council

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This can be a limitation on the server where the code is running. Every operating system only allows for a certain number of open files/handles/sockets. This limit is usually further reduced when the server is virtualized. On a Linux server you can check the current limit with `ulimit -n`, if you have root access you can increase it with the same command. I assume there is a method for Windows server as well. Otherwise there is not much you can do about it (except ask your hoster or administrator to increase it).

More configurable limits:

Change in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
soft nofile 1024
hard nofile 65535
```

Increase ulimit by `ulimit -n 65535`
or `echo 65535 > /proc/sys/fs/file-max`  or in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
fs.file-max=65535
```

Comment: $ ulimit -n > 256. I'm on OSX

Comment: @Mauro I get 4864 on Mavericks (OSX 10.9)

Comment: @JamesHalsall I'm using 1024 now

Comment: In my case, this occurred no matter how high I set `ulimit -n` (I even tried 1,000,000). The problem turned-out to be bad logic in the PHP classes I was testing. For what it's worth, I was using Laravel and had a Factory State that returned a non-scalar value without using the closure syntax; I fixed the issue by using the closure syntax, and then a `ulimit -n` of `2048` was plenty.

Answer (score 35):

How can you up file open limit (Linux or Max OS):

```
ulimit -n 10000
```

Solves problem with `phpunit` or/and `phpdbg` and `Warning:  Uncaught ErrorException: require([..file]): failed to open stream: Too many open files in  [...]`

Comment: it works only for users in login if you login as root: your root get ulimit 10000 but not your service like php mysql

Answer (score 6):

In php, before the execution, try this

```
exec('ulimit -S -n 2048');
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Tried to add this line in both `setUp()` and `setUpBeforeClass()` methods. Executing it manually on the terminal before launching unit tests does work however.

Comment: @Koen Same for me. I guess the PHP process doesn't have permission to change this on the OS level.

Answer (score 3):

After 'waking' my computer from sleep mode I ran into this problem.

Restarting php-fpm like so fixed it. Classic turn it off & back on again solution.

`sudo /etc/init.d/php-fpm restart`

I think this may be related to xdebug which I recently added to php.

Answer (score 2):

Don't store DirectoryIterator objects for later; you will get an error saying "too many open files" when you store more than the operating system limit (usually 256 or 1024).

For example, this will yield an error if the directory has too many files:

```
<?php 
$files = array(); 
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('myDir') as $file) { 
    $files[] = $file; 
} 
?>
```

Presumably, this approach is memory intensive as well.

source: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/directoryiterator.construct.php#87425

Answer (score 1):

on server debian you can go to also to

***/etc/php/php7.xx/fpm/pool.d/www.conf***

> rlimit_files = 10000

```
/etc/init.d/php7.xx restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you have some error with file `/etc/init.d/phpx.x-fpm`. 
Let’s restart it:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this occur in PHP when you forget to wrap something in a closure. Carefully look at your recent diffs and you might be able to get to the bottom of this (in my case, I referenced `$faker` in a Laravel PHP unit factory without having a closure.

Answer (score 1):

I experience this error in relation to a Http pool, where I added too many urls into the pool (around 2000 urls).

I had to chunk the urls into smaller batches, and the error stopped.

I think its how the Guzzle Pool works, it doesn't close the curl connections before the entire pool is done.

**Ex.**

```
$responses = Http::pool(function (Pool $pool) use ($chunk) {
    return collect($chunk)->map(fn($url) => $pool->get($url));
});
```

**Becomes:**

```
collect($urls)
    ->chunk(25)
    ->each(function ($chunk) {
        $responses = Http::pool(function (Pool $pool) use ($chunk) {
            return collect($chunk)->map(fn($url) => $pool->get($url));
        });
    });
```

The Http function is a wrapper function from Laravel using Guzzle Http Client. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, every time about a Redis library PHP was trying to load, but it was caused by something I didn't really think of at first. I kept getting this error when my program was running a while, doing a repetitive process. I found out I opened a cURL session (`$ch = new curl_init(...)`), which was closed in the destructor of a class, but that destructor was never called. I fixed that problem and the too-many-files open error disappeared.