# PHP "failed to open stream - too many open files" error

Tags: php, runtime-error, fopen, fclose

I'm getting the PHP error

```
failed to open stream: Too many open files.
```

I suspect the problem is that I'm not closing something properly, but to find out what, I need to get a list of currently open files when this error occurs. How do I find this information? This is on a shared Apache server.

Thanks.

Comment: In Linux you can use `lsof` to get a list of open files. For windows you can use `openfiles`

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I will try to include a call to lsof in my PHP error handling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal Error - Too many open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748499/fatal-error-too-many-open-files)