# AMP Parallel: failed to open stream: Too many open files in ClassLoader.php

Tags: php, multithreading, composer-php, amphp

While using AMPHP libraries for thread working tasks, I suddenly got the Warning and Error:

```
PHP Warning:  include(/.../vendor/amphp/process/lib/ProcessException.php): failed to open stream: Too many open files in /.../vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 445
```

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Amp\Failure' not found
```

This was previously working fine, and started to get the issue recently.

Using:

- PHP 7.4.21 (cli)
- macOS
- "amphp/parallel-functions": "^1.0"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal Error - Too many open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748499/fatal-error-too-many-open-files)

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks for the suggestion. Thinking this from a person having this issue in the future with PHP thread worker: which question are they most likely to find: this one, or a generic one related to PHPUnit Tests and multiple solutions? On the other Question, one of the proposals is increasing `ulimit` indeed, but I took the time to write this question and answer for people with the same issue, specifically with PHP thread workers

Answer (score 0):

According to a thread on AMPHP GitHub issue page: https://github.com/amphp/parallel-functions/issues/22

On macOS, the ulimit is by default 1024.

In my case, upgrading that to `ulimit -n 4096` as suggested, worked fine.

According to IBM docs: "ulimit sets or displays the resource limits on processes created by the user." [More info](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=descriptions-ulimit-set-process-limits).